# Using SaveChangesAsync in RavenDB

Tags: c#, asynchronous, insert, nosql, ravendb

I am inserting a lot of data into a RavenDB database; about 2`500`000 records. That needs to be completed in less time as possible.

I use a list to hold Task object returned by SaveChangesAsync:

```
session.Store(loc);

splitter++;
if (splitter % 2048 == 0)
{
    var t = session.SaveChangesAsync();
    tasks.Add(t);

    if (tasks.Count == 2)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        tasks.Clear();
    }
}
```

This code is running on machine with an i7 (8 core) and 12 GB ram. It works if the number of Task objects I hold is 2 (as you see in the code) but if I increase this number to 8 (number of cores) I receive a System.IndexOutOfRangeException (and sometimes an System.AggregateException which says: "Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.ConcurrencyException: PUT attempted on document 'X/I' using a non current etag").

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of the tasks collection? Are you trying to limit the number of tasks? Is it a type safe collection?

Comment: "tasks" is of type List<Task> and yes I have used it for limiting number of tasks AND the other reason is I ALWAYS get one of those exceptions by just calling SaveChangesAsync repeatedly.

Comment: So you are trying to save the changes in a session, while still making changes to it? I doubt if this can work. It could only work if SaveChangesAsync first made a copy of all changes, to allow you to keep adding modifications while it saved the existing ones. This is highly unlikely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have only a single async pending operation per sessions.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with this code:

- You are trying to save changes while still adding changes to the session.
- You are scheduling another SaveChangesAsync before the first one finishes. This is what probably raises the ConcurrencyException

At the very least you should wait for each SaveChangesAsync call to finish before scheduling another.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the whole async thing a waste?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [BulkInsert](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/bulk-inserts).  It's meant for saving a lot of data to the database, because async won't help you.